# Using .Random.seed in R functions

Tags: random, random-seed, seed

I am trying to get the seed in R and use it in functions and it does not work.
I found that one can get the seed using `.Random.seed` and it works perfectly when I do not include it in a function. Here is an example.

```
seed         <- .Random.seed  #save the local seed
.Random.seed <- seed          #use the saved seed
sum(rnorm(100))
.Random.seed <- seed          #use the saved seed
sum(rnorm(100))
```

As we can see, I save the current seed (local seed) in the object `seed`. I can then use that seed later by giving it to `.Random.seed`. Thus, `sum(rnorm(100))` will return the same value. I try to do the same thing using a function and it does not work.

```
f  <- function(seed){
  .Random.seed <- seed
  cat(sum(seed), sum(.Random.seed), "\n") 
  sum(rnorm(100))
}
f(seed)
f(seed)  #the value changed
```

I use `cat` to print .Random.seed in order to make sure that it does not change and it does not. Nevertheless the `rnorm(100)` changes. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution. In the function, I only changed `.Random.seed` in the function's environment and not in the global environment. It works if I change `.Random.seed` in the global environment.

```
f  <- function(seed){
  assign(".Random.seed", seed, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  cat(sum(seed), sum(.Random.seed), "\n")
  sum(rnorm(100))
}
f(seed)
f(seed)
```